# Cannot get the input value using click event in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am new to meteor and am having some problem in click event.

The code is:

```
Template.addPost.events({
 'click button':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var postName=event.target.postName.value;
    Posts.insert({
      name:postName,
      createdAt:new Date()
    });
    event.target.postName.value='';
  }
});
```

HTML code is:

```
<template name='addPost'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Add post here' name='postName'>
  <button class="btn btn" type="button">Post</button>
</template>
```

However in the browser on clicking the button the input value is not inserted to the mongo database.

Comment: Are you sure the event is not fired? May be event fires but adding to collection fails because of missing permission? You can console.log in event handler to be sure if it fires or not

Comment: var postName=event.target.postName.value; <-- postName is not inside event.target. Try to debug a bit first. console.log(event.target) or give id to input id="myinput" -> var postName =  $('#myinput').val();

Comment: @iiro Sir I placed console.log(postName); before Posts.insert and it didn't show anything in the console.However on giving id='myinput' and using var postName = $('#myinput').val(); it worked perfectly.Can u please tell me why is it not working using the javascript code..

Comment: @Areca Sir I placed console.log(postName); before Posts.insert and it didn't show anything in the console.However on giving id='myinput' and using var postName = $('#myinput').val(); it worked perfectly.Can u please tell me why is it not working using the javascript code..

Comment: i told you to see console.log(event.target) and see what it gives :) 

The reason why your code does not work is that event.target doesn't have a property called 'postName'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event is on the button but you want to refer to the value of the input field in your insert. You already have a `name` for your `input` field so you can refer to it using jQuery and a name selector:

```
Template.addPost.events({
 'click button': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var postName = $('input[name="postName"]').val();
    Posts.insert({ name: postName, createdAt: new Date() });
    $('input[name="postName"]').val('');
  }
});
```

Comment: Sir in javascript 'postName' doesn't work since it is not a part of event target(button),but using jQuery  'postName' works fine.Why is it so?

Comment: jQuery looks at the entire DOM and selects the element(s) you want based on the _selector_ - in this case `'input[name="postName"]'`

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the value of postName input with

```
var postName=event.target.postName.value;
```

postName is not a member of event target (which is button itself).
Adding an id attribute to input and accessing the value over it would solve your problem. So access it with:

```
postName = $('#myinput').val();
```

Comment: Another option to allow for proper targeting of the input field data is to put the inputs and button in a form. Then using the buttons as "submit" the form fields will be accessible through `target.<field name>.value` also, since the `<form>` is now the target.

Comment: Thanks now I get it.As 'id' is a global attribute hence it should be use instead of name attribute.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The information that you've provided is very limited. There are a couple of different scenarios there.

Are you sure you're calling the right event? Above your Posts.insert() method, try to console.log the postName variable.

Have you gotten rid of the autopublish and insecure packages?

Comment: Sir as u mentioned I placed console.log(postName); before Posts.insert and it didn't show anything in the console.

Comment: Don't forget to check also the CLI. If it shows the "undefined" or something like that, then you're calling the right method, but getting the wrong input. If you see nothing at all, as you mentioned, then try checking your events. Start from there. Good luck. :)